# How can you pass text strings using Arrays through UISliders?

Tags: ios, arrays, nsstring, uislider

How can I make my sliders step through my Arrays?  Right now they are set up as tests just to show numbers.

```
    @implementation ViewController

    - (IBAction)shapeSlider:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    float val = slider.value;
    self.shapeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",val];
}
    - (IBAction)colorSlider:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider2 = (UISlider *)sender;
    float val = slider2.value;
    self.colorLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",val];
}
  - (IBAction)cutSlider:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider3 = (UISlider *)sender;
    float val = slider3.value;
    self.cutLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",val];
}
  - (IBAction)PriceSlider:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider4 = (UISlider *)sender;
    NSInteger val = lround(slider4.value);
    self.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d",val];
}

    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField

{
    [[self zipCode] resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [[self view] endEditing:YES];

}
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[    super viewDidLoad];


    // set price slider values
    self.priceSlider.minimumValue = 1000;
    self.priceSlider.maximumValue = 200000;

    // create Arrays

    self.shapes = @[@"Round", @"Princess", @"Emerald", @"Asscher", @"Marquise", @"Oval",         @"Radiant", @"Pear", @"Heart", @"Cushion"];

    self.colors = @[@"J", @"I", @"H", @"G", @"F", @"E", @"D"];
```

I have tried many things, but it seems that a lot of posts are old and Xcode 5 isn't accepting any shenanigans.

I also need to take whatever the user selects and post to an email using a submit button.  Is this possible without the user having mail set up on their iOS device?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works perfectly, based on a different answer I found right here at stackoverflow.com

```
 - (IBAction)shapeSlider:(id)sender {
     UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
     NSInteger sliderValue = (NSInteger)slider.value;
     self.shapeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_shapes        objectAtIndex:sliderValue]];
```

Basically the slider has to have a maximum and minimum value along with an Array that has the same maximum value of strings within it.